# How do i check if the url i enter in the textBox is appears in the List?

Tags: c#

I have a List type of dictionary> called LocalyKeyWords.
And i have a new form where there is a textBox where i can type a new url address its called     cl.getText().

When i click the button its showing a new form with only a textBox.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl = new ChangeLink();
            cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cl.Close();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {    
                    label4.Text = cl.getText();
                    mainUrl = cl.getText();
                    for (int i = 0; i < LocalyKeyWords.Count(); i++ )
                    {
                        if (LocalyKeyWords[i].Contains(cl.getText()))
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
                    cl.Close();
            } 


        }
```

I want to check if the url the user enter in the cl.getText() already exist in the LocalyKeyWords List so i tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LocalyKeyWords.Count(); i++ )
                    {
                        if (LocalyKeyWords[i].Contains(cl.getText()))
                        {

                        }
                    }
```

But its not working. 
I want to loop through all the items in List and in the end if the cl.getText() not exist in any of the items in the List do something.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but are you saying that `LocalyKeyWords` is a list of dictionaries? Can you show the declaration of `LocalyKeyWords`?

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is incomplete, but you could use this

```
        Dictionary<int, string> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        LocalyKeyWords.Add(0, "dog");
        LocalyKeyWords.Add(1, "lizard");
        LocalyKeyWords.Add(2, "cat");

        for (int i = 0; i < LocalyKeyWords.Count()-1; i++)
        {
            if (LocalyKeyWords[i].Contains( "lizard" ) )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Found the lizard");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Used contains. The declaration of the List is: Dictionary<string, List<string>> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); and i just used if(!LocalyKeywords.Contains(....)) Thanks. Its working.